# Tab Key Stops Moving Between Input Fields

Tags: material-ui

For the time being, this is a Material-UI question.

I have a situation where the tab key ceases to move the text cursor between TextFields.  At the moment, I have no idea where in my code this is happening, and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction so I can start looking.

Here’s the setup:

1. A mouse click causes a Dialog to be displayed.  The Dialog has
   several TextFields as well as 2 FlatButtons, “cancel & “submit”
2. At this state, tabbing between fields works as expected.
3. If I hit the “cancel” button, an event is fired which updates state (including the display of the Dialog) and the Dialog is closed.  I can repeat the process from the top with no issues.
4. If I hit the “submit” button, an event is fired which does some async stuff (using rxjs epics).
5. On success, the epic fires an event which updates the state (including the display of the Dialog)
6. If I now try to repeat the process from the top, the tab key does not respond.

I am in the process of migrating to v1, and checked some of the v0.* components – they have the same problem – I don’t recall that being an issue before… Possible conflict between the two versions of the library?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Yes, there is a conflict between the v0.20 and v1.0 of the Dialog component.  At least when you have one opening on top of another.  Having changed all Dialogs to v1.0, the problem disappeared.

By the way, its not that the tab key wasn't responding - it was responding in the lower Dialog component and not in the top (latest to be created) one.  This problem disappeared once the same version was used for both.